# Probability of genetic inheritance (brainteaser)

Tags: probability

I recently came across the following probability brainteaser and I'm trying to figure out the cleanest solution:

Suppose that there are ten 'genes' that determine tallness. Each gene is made up of two bits, which can be either 1 or 0. So each of the ten genes may be 00, 01, 10, or 11. A person's height is completely determined by the number of '11' genes that they have. So a person with five '11' genes has height five.

Inheritance works as follows: For each gene, we randomly pick whether the first or second bit is from the male. The other bit comes from the female. So for instance if the male has a gene 01 and the female has a gene 10, we could get offspring genes 00 or 11.

If both parents have height 7, what's the expected height of the offspring assuming that the bits of the 3 remaining non-'11' genes are uniformly distributed?

(The person who gave this question to me asserted it could be done without long combinatoric calculations, but I don't see how to do that).

Comment: What's funny is that unless these people are immortal or everybody begins with height $10$, the tallest person's height will tend to $0$ in the limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the height of a single gene is $1$ if the gene is `11` and is $0$ otherwise. Since the height of the person is the sum of the heights of these ten genes, by linearity and symmetry the expected height is equal to ten times the expected height of a single gene, say the first one. The probability distribution for a single gene is fairly easy to calculate: `11` has probability $7/10$ and each of `10`, `01`, `00` have probability $(1-7/10)/3=1/10$. From here we can split into cases:

- If the parents are `(11,11)` the probability of getting `11` is $1$.
- If the parents are `(10,11)`, `(01,11)`, `(11,10)`, `(11,01)` the probability is $1/2$.
- If the parents are `(01,10)` or `(10,01)` the probability is $1/2$.

Adding and multiplying everything up, we get

$${\Bbb E}({\rm height})=10\left[\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^2+4\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]=6.4 $$